# How to set a YARN queue from within a SparkR session?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

If I'm initializing a Spark session using SparkR (not `spark-submit`), like this...

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session()
```

is there a way to set a queue? I tried something like this:

```
sparkR.session(queue = "queue_name")
```

but it didn't seem to work. The only way I've successfully used a queue from within SparkR is with the deprecated `init()` function:

```
sc <- SparkR::sparkR.init(master = "yarn-client", sparkEnvir = list(spark.yarn.queue="queue-name")) 
hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
```

But that throws warnings: `'SparkR::sparkR.init' is deprecated.`

How does this translate to `sparkR.session()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting spark R, the Spark Session is already generated. 
You need to stop the current session and spin up a new one to set the desired settings.

I use the following

```
sparkR.stop()
sparkR.session(
    # master="local[2]",              # local master
    master="yarn",                    # cluster master
    appName="my_sparkR",
    sparkConfig=list(
        spark.driver.memory="4g",
        spark.executor.memory="2g",
        spark.yarn.queue="your_desired_queue"
    )
)
```

Verify from the Spark monitoring page that the settings updated correctly.

Comment: This works great; I couldn't find it so clearly stated anywhere else, thank you. For clarity's sake, I'm actually launching this from a Rscript job, so the ```sparkR.stop()``` isn't strictly necessary, but this is much appreciated.